# Error: spawn ENOENT for png files when using grunt-contrib-imagemin

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-imagemin

I am trying to compress images with `grunt-contrib-imagemin ~0.9.4` in a `node.js` application. My config is:

```
    imagemin: {
        dynamic: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'server/static/img/',
                src: ['**/*.{jpg,gif,png}'],
                dest: '_public/incl/img/'
            }]
        }
    },
```

I systematically get a `Error: spawn ENOENT in file somepath/someimage.png` message. It fails at the first processed `.png` file. When I don't include `.png` files, it all works fine.

I have read somewhere that I should copy the image files first in the target directory as a workaround. I have tried this, but it does not solve the issue.

I am on Windows 7 32-bits and I am using `grunt ~0.4.5`. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Did you try to disable the cache with `options: { cache: false }`?

Comment: I just did, but it did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 7):

Blow away node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin and try and do a `npm install` again. The node equivalent of “did you restart it”?

[image]

I see in their [github repo](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-imagemin/issues) they have a couple of issues related to pngs, but nothing like you are seeing.

Answer (score 3):

just reinstall the image-webpack-loader. That's worked for me.

Comment: This should be comment.

Answer (score 3):

This `rebuild` fixed my problem.

> [**Laravel Mix Issues Optimising Images in Sass Files | Andy Carter**](https://andy-carter.com/blog/laravel-mix-issues-optimising-images-in-sass-files)
>
> > ```
> >  $ npm rebuild mozjpeg  
> >  $ npm rebuild gifsicle  
> >  $ npm rebuild optipng-bin
> > ```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be caused by a recent change in a package that imagemin is dependent on. The new setup doesn't support proxies until someone fixes it. 
https://github.com/kevva/download/issues/64

[This thread](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8682) suggests downgrading bin-build from 2.1.2 to 2.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the node_modules folder and then run `npm install` or `npm i` to install all the modules again